How to output multiline string returned by function with `http.server`?
So I have a basic http server running and for the most part it does what I want, but I want to improve on it.
I am brand new to http.server and quite new to Python still.
I have been able to print my function out fine as a list, however when I iterate over it then try it only prints one item.
Here is the code;
def outFunc():
    tup = getInfo()
    out = list(sum(tup, ()))
    # out_2 =' '.join(map(str,out))
    for item in out:
        return out

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>Most Recent Domains</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes(f"<p>{outFunc()}</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

Here it prints one item as mentioned if I change the function outFunc to instead to just return out instead of the loop it lists all the items fine.
My question is how do I print the loop output onto the web page in a p HTML tag for example?

Since I don't know the result of getInfo(), I'll try giving you a solution:
This code is to print each result of the tuple inside a <p> tag.
def out_func():
    tup = getInfo()
    return list(sum(tup, ()))


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>Most Recent Domains</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        [self.wfile.write(bytes(f"<p>{x}</p>", "utf-8")) for x in out_func()]
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

I also never used http.server so I admit I didn't test this. But simply, looping through the tuple, you append a p tag for each element!
One more edit I've made to your code is snake_case for functions!

The server part is irrelevant, your function returns only the first value, because it's exactly what you have written :)
Test it with print(outFunc())

Using print and not return prints to console not the webpage, do you mean place print function inside the self.wfile.write? Also what do you mean it only prints one because that is what I wrote? Because when I use the same function I wrote using print as mentioned it prints all of the items iterated in the list in console just fine.

I just tried adding print to the function prints to console, I also tried adding to the {} within self.wfile.write, prints to console. I need to print all the items in the list to the webpage not the console.

@Z.Davey, your code writes to HTTP response the string returned by function.  Your function returns only one value, the first element of the list.  What you need is a loop in do_GET iterating through the list and writing all values to server output

That's news to me? I thought a for loop iterated through all the list? Since when I use that function elsewhere it returns all items just fine? How does putting the loop inside the function which is inside the class change things?

I just tried your advice and placed the for loop inside the class and function do_GET. If I print item vs return item it prints the list fine to console, if I return item it prints only one item on the site. I also just realized there is a typo on my main question it's meant to obviously say return item not out.

@Z.Davey: "I thought a for loop iterated through all the list?" — not if you explicitly break or return from it.

@Z.Davey: "I also just realized there is a typo on my main question" — Please edit your question then, and a) change it to something we can run ourselves; b) include expected output.

Could you fix the typo in the question?

@5rod, do you mean me or the OP?

My apologies, @NikolajŠ. I mean to say, "Could you fix the typo in the answer?"

@5rod, what typo?  Sorry, I can't spot it.

@NikolajŠ, it should be print(outFunc()) not print(outFinc()).

@5rod, ha, I must be blind, thanks
